# How to set delegate to UIActivityViewController of QLPreviewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiactivityviewcontroller, qlpreviewcontroller

My application's navigation bar buttons color is white..
So I used below code to set color for entire application.

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:fontColor];
```

QLPreviewContoller by default having option for UIActivityViewController so while opening MailComposer from UIActivityViewController I am getting white navigation bar button because I have used **appearance**

Attached screenshot for reference.
Can anybody help me in solving this issue?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is not with QLPreviewController or UIActivityViewController. May be you don't set any colour for navigationBar, by default navigation bar will take white colour as background colour and you are also setting white colour for bar buttons so result will be like above image only. Try to set colour navigation bar using appearance then you can see bar button items.